# How do I completely bootstrap a grails environment?

Tags: grails, bootstrapping

I have the included grails script that I found in some random place on the internet and it works pretty well for firing up scripts in a bootstrapped grails env. The only thing it doesn't seem to do is kick off my `conf/*Bootstrap.groovy` scripts like when I do run-app.

Is there another function like `loadApp()` and `configureApp()` that will do that for me?

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.support.PersistenceContextInterceptor

Ant.property(environment: "env")
grailsHome = Ant.antProject.properties."env.GRAILS_HOME"

includeTargets << new File("${grailsHome}/scripts/Bootstrap.groovy")

target('default': "Runs scripts in the test/local directory") {
    if (!args) { throw new RuntimeException("[fail] This script requires an argument - the script to run.") }

    depends(configureProxy, packageApp, classpath)
    classLoader = new URLClassLoader([classesDir.toURI().toURL()] as URL[], rootLoader)
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader)
    loadApp()
    configureApp()

    def interceptor = null
    def beanNames = appCtx.getBeanNamesForType(PersistenceContextInterceptor)
    if (beanNames && beanNames.size() == 1) {
        interceptor = appCtx.getBean(beanNames[0])
    }
    try {
        interceptor?.init()
        new GroovyScriptEngine(Ant.antProject.properties."base.dir", classLoader).run("scripts/${args}.groovy", new Binding(['appCtx':appCtx]))
        interceptor?.flush()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        interceptor?.clear()
    } finally {
        interceptor?.destroy()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try

> new BootStrap().init()

Comment: yeah.. you have to do that in a script running in the same scriptengine.. it won't run right in the gant script as shown.. 

I just added an Init.groovy that can call any bootstrap stuff and I run it in the same instance of the script engine I run the actual script in. 

thanks!